# get images which are in a specified element

Tags: javascript, dom

`document.images` contains full list of all `<img>` tags in the HTML file..

Can I get just `img` tags which are placed in a specified element? (for example which one has `images_list` class) Something like this:

`document.getElementById('images').images`

Thanks ...

Comment: are you using any js library like jquery?

Comment: @Kishore: no, libraries are a bit heavy for my users... (jQuery way is simple, I know this.. `$('.images_list img')`

Answer (score 3):

If your container element is in a variable named `container` as shown below, then you can do this in plain javascript:

```
<div id="box">
    <img src="xxx">
    <img src="yyy">
</box>

var container = document.getElementById("box");
var imgs = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

In modern browsers, you can use a built-in selector function:

```
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll("#box img");
```

If using the jQuery library, you can use:

```
var imgs = $("#box img");
```

If using the Sizzle selector library (which is the selector library inside of jQuery or available separately), you can use:

```
var imgs = Sizzle("#box img");
```

Show us you HTML and we can answer more specifically to your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using JQuery or another library and can use an `id` instead of a class you could do this:

```
​var cont = document.getElementById("image_list");
var img = cont.getElementsByTagName("img");
console.log(img);


​<div id="image_list">
<img id="img1" src="" />
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

But I would recommend using JQuery.  You could do this above with a class but it would be a lot more code.

There is a `getElementsByClassName` method but it is not supported by browsers like IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Here is a demo, I included a jquery example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/TJn7A/1/